# multiple forms with jquery serialize method not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have multiple form and each form is getting submitted but not the first one.

I tried everything like `event.preventDefault();`

MY CODE :

```
<?php for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
<form id="form<?php echo $i; ?>>
<td><?php echo $i++ ?><td>
<td><input type="text" name="detention_unloading_charges"   value="<?php echo $history[$i]->name; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="dtn_chrg_per_day" value="<?php echo $history[$i]->dtn_chrg_per_day; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="text"  name="dtn_chrg" value="<?php echo $history[$i]->dtn_chrg; ?>"></td>
<td>
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="save_changes(<?php echo $i ?>);">Save Changes</button></td>
</form>
}
```

and jquery function:

```
function save_changes(id)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "History/update",
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#form'+id).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            // Success message
            console.log(data);
            if(data==1){
                $('.success_pop_up').addClass('show').removeClass('d-none');
            } else{
                $('.failure_pop_up').addClass('show').removeClass('d-none');;
            }
        }
   });
}
```

Comment: keep the $i++ below <button>

Comment: @gracie williams that makes no sense at all

Comment: He is using echo unnecessarily , which also increments $i apart from for loop , so loop runs only thrice and form id is form0 but corresponding function is save_changes(1) , where that form does not exist at all

Comment: @gracie Williams then the solution is to delete the extra $i++, not move it somewhere else (which is what you suggested in your first comment)

Comment: yupe sorry , to delete it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are incrementing $i twice in the beginning itself by `echo $i++`,  which also increments $i apart from for loop , so loop runs only thrice and form id is form0 but corresponding function is save_changes(1) , where that form id does not exist at all , try below code.

```
    <?php for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){ ?>
    <form id="form<?php echo $i; ?>>
    <td><?php echo $i?><td>
    <td><input type="text" name="detention_unloading_charges"   value="<?php echo $history[$i]->name; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="dtn_chrg_per_day" value="<?php echo $history[$i]->dtn_chrg_per_day; ?>"></td>
    <td><input type="text"  name="dtn_chrg" value="<?php echo $history[$i]->dtn_chrg; ?>"></td>
    <td>
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="save_changes(<?php echo $i ?>);">Save Changes</button></td>
    </form>    
    <?php  } ;?>
```

Try this code and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to solve this the following way:

Let the button do a default submit like so:

```
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

Catch the submit event for your form in jQuery:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    // Prevent default so the browser doesnt automatically submit it.
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    // ... send it
});
```

This way it is much easier to do AJAX form requests.